# Override plugin functions in functions.php

Tags: plugins, functions, updates

I´d like to override `$title = get_bloginfo();` with --> `$title = get_bloginfo('siteurl');`

Some code from the plugin "[Really simple Facebook Twitter share buttons](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons/)":

```
function really_simple_share ($content, $filter, $link='', $title='', $author='') {
    static $last_execution = '';

    ...

    $custom_field_disable = get_post_custom_values('really_simple_share_disable');
    if ($custom_field_disable[0]=='yes' and $filter!='shortcode') {
        return $content;
    }

    //GET ARRAY OF STORED VALUES
    global $really_simple_share_option;
    $option = $really_simple_share_option;

    ...

    $first_shown = false; // NO PADDING FOR THE FIRST BUTTON

    // IF LINK AND TITLE ARE NOT SET, USE DEFAULT FUNCTIONS
    if ($link=='' and $title=='') {
        $link = ($option['use_shortlink']) ? wp_get_shortlink() : get_permalink();

        $title = get_bloginfo(); // OVERRIDE

        $author = get_the_author_meta('nickname');
    }
```

Can I do this in my functions.php because I´ll updating this plugin without changing this lines after every update.

Thanks

Comment: May I ask *why* you want the title to be the site URL?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: I´ll use this custom title as description in a pinterest post.

Comment: Just checked out the full plugin source - can't see a reliable filter/action to depend on. I suggest you contact the author & encourage them to add plugin-specific hooks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to filter the `get_bloginfo()`, but you'll have to find a way to fine tune the conditional, because the override is **global**...

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_blogname', 'wpse_58030_override_blogname' );

function wpse_58030_override_blogname( $bool )
{
    // If not page with ID == 28, do nothing
    if( !is_page( 28 )  ) 
        return false;
        
    // Change the 'blogname'
    return "Not The Blog Name";
}
```

[image]

#### Observation

`get_bloginfo()` is the same as `get_bloginfo('blogname')`.

If the desired filter was `siteurl`, the filter would be `pre_option_siteurl`.

Comment: This works great. THANKS. I´d like to override: '$title = get_the_title();' with '$title = get_bloginfo('siteurl');' Does it work, too?

Comment: That depends on how the function `really_simple_share` is being called...

Comment: Thanks. I share the whole PHP-Script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4912qn8yhpxkmn/really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons.php // LINE 219

Comment: Damn, that's an awesome filter I was never aware of. Thanks, @brasofilo! +1

Comment: @JohannesPille : *Hook Hunters* is the name of the movie :)